# Electric Force in Vacuum

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, classical-electrodynamics

Lets say we have a point charge $A$ in a vacuum, and a similarly charged point $B$ some distance away which detects the field, and feels a force of attraction or repulsion. There are electric field lines that propagate from $A$ to the space around, and some of these reach $B$. But how does point $B$ feel this force from $A$? At first I thought it was the photons, as electromagnetic wave carriers, but then that implies a finite amount of carrier particles, so there must be places where $B$ can be put so that it feels no force. Clearly, this is incorrect...

Comment: The electromagnetic interaction is carried by virtual photons, not real photons. Virtual photons are exitations of the quantum field. Why do you think a finite number of them is not sufficient? It is.

Comment: The way I thought of the photons is like little balls all flying out of point A. Now consider a large hypothetical sphere, where A is the center and B is at the surface. But then the photons would only hit certain surface area components of the sphere, and may miss B. This clearly does not happen, so what is the error in my logic?

Comment: You are digging deep into the mystery of nature :) Before too long you'll face a wall of impenetrable mathematics. Charges are described by quantum fields of probability. When two charges are near, their fields interact in such a way that the probability of them to exchange energy, momentum, and spin increases. The quantum nature of the fields dictates that such exchanges must be in certain portions (quants) that resemble photons. They don't actually exist, but are just a description of the interaction, so they are called virtual. So A shoots a virtual photon directly at B and feels a recoil.

Comment: So we can not (yet) really understand what goes on in this quantum world, so we summarize the difficulties by assuming there are virtual photons which go from one charged particle to another?

Comment: Not exactly. Here you need to define what you mean by "understand". If you mean, describe in terms of everyday common sense, then the quantum world has its own different sense that is not describable in everyday terms. And if you mean, describe what happens with a measurable precision, then QED is the most precise theory ever created by the humankind matching measurements better than one part in a trillion. Furthermore, we do know the fundamental cause for electromagnetism as a result of this universe having the U(1) and Lorentz symmetries (roughly speaking, "circles are round in spacetime").